# If $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ divides $f(x+2)f(x-2)$, find the minimum value of $f$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am stuck with this Precalculus problem about polynomial functions. The problem:

> Consider $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ with $a^2-4b>0$. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of $f$. Assume that $f(x)$ divides $f(x+2)f(x-2)$. Then
>
> 1. Show that $\alpha=\beta+2$ or $\alpha=\beta-2$
> 2. Using $1.$, find the minimum value of $f(x)$.

Part $1$ is easy: write $f(x+2)f(x-2)=f(x)g(x)$ and substitute $x=\alpha$ to obtain $f(\alpha+2)f(\alpha-2)=0$, so $\alpha+2$ or $\alpha-2$ is a root of $f$. This root cannot be $\alpha$, so $\alpha+2=\beta$ or $\alpha-2=\beta$.

I am stuck with part $2$. **Any idea**?

The minimum is obtained at $-\frac{a}{2}=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}=\beta+1$ or $\beta-1$ but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then the minimum occurs at 
$x_{min} = \dfrac{\alpha + \beta}{2}$.

$$\begin{align}
   f(x_{min})
      &= (x_{min} - \alpha)(x_{min} - \beta) \\
      &= -\dfrac{(\alpha-\beta)^2}{4}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$ f(x) = ( x - \alpha) ( x - \beta) = (x - c + 1)( x - c - 1) = (x-c)^2 - 1$

Hence, the minimum value is -1.

Answer (score 0):

By parallely translating the graph of the given $f(x)$, we can get the graph of any $g(x)=x^2+cx+d$. So it is sufficient to find the minimum of any $g(x)$ whose solutions is 2 apart: for example, $x(x-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of a monic quadratic the minimum value is $-(\frac{\alpha -\beta}{2})^2$. This is $-1$ for your quadratic.